# Meaning of cross-correlation results with Matlab (xcorr)

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, correlation, cross-correlation

I have two recorded measurements and I would like to know their phase shift at different frequencies. I have already used xcorr to find the time delay that gives me the highest correlation. But, what does that time delay refer to? Let's say I get a value. I know that is the number of samples needed in order to shift my signal and get the highest correlation. But, is it an average? What if I want to know the phase shift for those signals at different frequencies?

Is that time lag the same for all the frequencies? Or is it just an average?

Thank you

Comment: `xcorr` knows nothing about frequency. It works in the time domain. If you want to know phase shifts for different frequencies you may need to apply `fft` to both signals

Comment: @LuisMendo So you are saying I cannot link the time delay I get from 'xcorr' to the phase shift between the two signals?

Comment: Delay can only be linked to phase if you define the frequency (or frequencies) you are using

Comment: That's exactly what I am asking. I know the time delay from xcorr and the frequencies contained in the time signals. Is correct to link that time delay to all the frequencies I am interested in to find the different phase shifts? Or is it an average or related to the dominant hamonic only?

Comment: It is probably a sort of messy average over frequencies, yes. You need to first isolate the same frequency component for the two the signals ( via `fft` perhaps) and then you can talk about the phase difference _at that frequency_. Of course, if the signals already are sinusoids that step can be avoided

Comment: Ok. So if I have two signals made of many overlapping sinusoids and I compute straight away the time lag using xcorr, that is useless,right?As it is an average with no real meaning to get the phase shift at the different frequencies of the sinusoids.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, as far as I know

Comment: One possible approach: correlate each signal with the same reference sinusoid at the desired frequency, obtain the time lags that maximize those two correlations, subtract them. That may work